# Place elements randomly into document background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to create a plugin for personal use, that will place clouds in my web page randomly.

Lets see now what is my idea:

I have create an image with all my clouds.

In my CSS I have create a general class called .cloud that is applyed to all cloud elements and four classes .cloud_1 .cloud_2 .cloud_3 .cloud_4 for each cloud element I like to place in my document.

Here are the css classes I use:

```
.cloud
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent url(../img/clouds.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.cloud_1
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cloud_2
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 469px;
    background-position: 0px -350px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.cloud_3
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 405px;
    background-position: 0px -819px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.cloud_4
{
    width: 630px;
    height: 314px;
    background-position: 0px -1225px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

From the other hand I use jQuery to place generate and place my clouds randomly into my document with random top and left.

The problem I have is that, if I set the position to absolute for .cloud selector the clouds that go out of the document width they activating the horizontal scroll bar. If I set it to fixed, the clouds are attached to the same position while I scroll down and so on.

What is the best solution in order to place my clouds with no horizontal scroll bar and not stay fixed in the same position ?

---

### Extra info

I forgot to tell you that the clouds will animated to the right !

---

### Produced code example

```
<div class="cloud cloud_3"></div>
```

and jQuery will adding style attributes like that:

```
<div class="cloud cloud_3" style="top: 280px; left: 120px;"></div>
```

Also jQuery will change the left css position in order to animated

Comment: How about the attributes 'top' and 'left' ?

Comment: What's the problem with limiting the random `left` value so that they do not cross the document width boundary?

Comment: The problem is the animation I will produce in a later step of the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all the clouds in a `<div>` with `overflow: hidden`, and make it the full size of your document.  Set that div to `z-index: -1` so that it is behind the rest of your content.

Answer (score 1):

Put the clouds into a containing div with`overflow: hidden` set on it. Then when the `left` position of the cloud is greater than the width of the containing div, move it back to the left so it will scroll accross to the right again.